# How do I find range of this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How do I find range of-

> $$y=\frac{\sqrt{x+7}-4}{x-9}$$

I think the traditional way of differentiating, finding critical points etc will be too hectic.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your function in the form
$$y=\frac{(\sqrt{x+7}-4)(\sqrt{x+7}+4)}{(x-9)(\sqrt{x+7}+4)}$$

Comment: So I get $1/\sqrt{x+7}+4$

Comment: You get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+7}+4}$, it's a big difference

Comment: Yep... I have got it

Comment: @Adam Thats what I wrote,right?

Comment: @tatan No, it's different. $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{1+1}\neq1/1+1=\frac{1}{1}+1=2$. Don't write like this on an exam.

Comment: @Adam We don't use straight line notation in exams...;-)

Comment: Note that $y$ is equal to the given expression ONLY when $x\ne9. \qquad$

Comment: @tatan : You get $ y = \begin{cases} \dfrac 1 {\sqrt{x+7} + 4} & \text{if } x\ne 9, \\ \text{no particular number} & \text{if } x=9. \end{cases} \qquad\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yep. Thanks prof!